# Android-How do i get image urls stored on a server then load the images using picasso

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp, image-loading, httpbackend

**Issues Faced**

I was able to get image url data using Okhttp but then store it on an arraylist but was faced with an issue because this processes takes time so when my activity start the view is seen before the data is received.

I am querying image urls from the server then displaying/loading them to a recycler view using picasso help please...?

Comment: Nice work! But why do you tell us?

Comment: To narrow down my question on the issue of  how can i load images after i get urls from the server---- english is not my first language

Comment: what is the question again

Comment: How do i get image urls stored on a server then load the images using picasso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the data from the api should be an asynchronous process, if you want to notify the user while that is happening, you can show a progress bar.

Upon receiving the data from the server, hide the progress bar and then load the images in the picasso, you can also specify a default image to picasso, which will be shown while the image itself is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use a progressDialog until receive your image urls from server and then dismiss it and then load it with picasso.

```
//before starting connection 
progressDialog.show();

//on Connection complete:
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show image using Picasso library using this code :

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(post_pic_url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_post)  // use a placeholder image here
.fit()  // to fit image on image view
.centerCrop()
.into(imgPost); // your image view object
```

If any explaination then please let me know in comments

Comment: The issue is not loading the images using picasso.But how to get the urls and show the image when the activity starts.

Comment: Are you using Async task ?  Your urls are you getting from any api ?

Comment: using okhttp hence on response i am getting all of my urls but the view seem to load before i get my data

Comment: are making your service call in onCreate ()  directly ?

Comment: yes i have a function called getData(); that get data from the server and stores it on an arraylist.. then a function called loadData(); that loads data on a a view

Comment: You should youse Async Task for server request.  Currently you are calling the server api in Main Thread directly , that is not a right approach.

Comment: Use Async task and do your api call in doInBackground()  and then use picasso library for imageview in onPostExecute()